# Глагол пробыть

Tags: ударение

Арабы "прОбыли" (?) в окружении четыре месяца.

Я не могу знать правильного ударения сего слова. Позволите ли вы спросить вас о нём?

Answer (score 1):

Пробы́ть.  Морфология: я пробу́ду, ты пробу́дешь, он/она/оно пробу́дет, мы пробу́дем, вы пробу́дете, они пробу́дут, пробу́дь, пробу́дьте, про́был и пробы́л, пробыла́, про́было и пробы́ло, ***про́были и пробы́ли***, пробы́вший…
dic.academic.ru[Здесь](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)